# How to flush pending messages and callbacks in a Handler

Tags: android, handler

How to flush/dispatch all pending messages and callbacks which are waiting in a Handler?

I need this to deal with certain asynchronous events when my Service is being destroyed.

I want to dispatch all the messages/callbacks immediately, not to remove them. I don't use any delayed messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't use any delayed messages, you have a queue of pending messages each of which must be processed in associated thread. This means that thread can not process next message unless current message processing is completed.

So, to summarize, if no delayed messages are used, you handler's message loop is already doing its best to flush the queue. The only thing that can make this flushing faster is better message processing. And this is not Handler's work.

Comment: I see your point I think. The methods of my service which run in the main thread, such as onDestroy(), are actually called as a result of messages being dispatched. So, I can not force message flushing within a such method, that is, while a message is being processed. I actually just found a solution, by using the Handler to post the events only if the current thread is different from the main service thread. Otherwise, I dispatch the events immediately. It fixes the problem in my case. I suppose this qualifies as "better message processing". Thanks

Comment: @inazaruk What's about the delayed messages? I have a similar scenario, but want to flush the delayed messages before onDestroyView is called. Is that possible?